# Does my product infringe on patent 5,344,396?

Tags: patent-infringement, us5344396

I have a product that is tubular but looks different and is pieced together to fit in skin tube and secured with a gripper. Used for restoring foreskin, am I infringing on this patent? Has this patent expired since issued before 1995? Patent is [5344396](http://www.google.com/patents/us5344396) filed 08/13/1992 and issued 09/06/1994.

Comment: A patent issued in 1994 would expire no later than 17 years later. In this case it co es to 2011.